# Primefaces 4.0 + Glassfish 3.1 resources CSS and JS are not loaded

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, glassfish

We're developing an web app using JSF + Primefaces + Springsecurity on a GlassFish server.

The problem is, when we had the app running on Tomcat, the resources of Primefaces (CSS and Javascript files) where loaded correctly, but on Glassfish, they don't.

We don't know if it is a Glassfish problem or an Spring security problem.

Look here:

**Netbeans + Primefaces 4.0 + Tomcat 7 WORKS:**
[image]

**Eclipse + Primefaces 4.0 + glassfish 3.1 DOESN'T WORK**
[image]

Help please!

Comment: Is there any specific code you can share to evaluate? Have you verified if the js/css files are being deployed and are accessible when deploying your application?

Answer (score -2):

Primefaces 4 is made for jsf 2.2 use glassfish4 then it works

Comment: While PF 4 targets for JSF 2.2, doesn't mean it won't work backwards. In fact, I'm using PF 4 in a project that runs on JBoss AS 7.1.1 and there's no problem (migrated to fix some bugs from PF 3.5).